# 2px spacing between contentheader and contentbox

Tags: html, css

Hee guy's,

I have this problem, I got spacing between the header and background image of the main contentbox. I can't solve out whats causing it.
I think it's a bit hard to know what I mean so if you could check out this link you will know what I mean. www.vazcreations.nl/design.

I don't think it's something big, if one of you could take a quick look, that would be awsome!

Thanks

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="mainheader">
<img src="main/main_header.png" alt=""/>
</div>
<div id="container">
```

CONTENT

```
</div>
<div class="mainfoot">
<img src="main/main_footer.png" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 175px;}

.mainheader {
    text-align:center;}

#header {
    background-image:url(header/header_bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:120px;
    text-align:center;}

#container {
     background-image:url(main/main_bg.png);
     background-repeat:repeat-y;
     background-position:center;
     width:871px;
     margin:0 auto;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left:0px;
     padding-right:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have white-space after image.

You can fix it by using any of these solutions:
1) Use main_header.png as a background image
2) Change it's 'display' to 'block' and center it with margin: 0 auto;
3) Set vertical-align: bottom for image (easier one)

Comment: I don't know if im stupid or so but nothing works by me... I should make changes to the css class .mainheader right?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the 2 `<br>`tags just above the #wrap div...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mainheader div is 49px in height
if you add height:47px; to your mainheader in your css file it will align properly

```
.mainheader {
    height: 47px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: After Css is altered]

Comment: You edited your post right? What means the "After css is altered"? And the value 1..?

Comment: You can download firebug extension for firefox if you want to inspect elements inside the browser it often helps to have them highlighted to see exactly where they begin and end. You can also inspect other peoples websites. I find it very useful while developing

Comment: yea that was a formatting error i just wanted to post an image